# Why late arrival event out of watermark not rejected

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I use Spark 2.4.3.

The late arrival data was not rejected.

I'm using structured streaming to read files from a folder. I expect the late arrival data can be excluded but it is still counted.

```
case class InputRow(...)

val df = spark.readStream
      .format("csv")
      .option("delimiter", ",")
      .schema(schema)
      .csv("/somefolder/")
... 
df.as[InputRow]
      .withWatermark("eventtime", "5 seconds")
      .groupBy($"eventid")
      .count()
      .writeStream.format("console")
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("3 seconds"))
      .option("truncate", false)
      .outputMode("update")
      .start
      .awaitTermination()
```

First time I put a file with a single row like:
2019-08-04 10:10:00,1,3328,c1,10,1000

eventid is 3328 here. The output is:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-------+-----+
|eventid|count|
+-------+-----+
|3328   |1    |
+-------+-----+

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+-------+-----+
|eventid|count|
+-------+-----+
+-------+-----+
```

Then I put another file with a single row like:
2019-08-02 10:10:00,1,3328,c1,10,1000
The eventid is the same, but the eventtime change to 8/2, which is obviously out of watermark (max time so far - 5seconds), but the output is:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+-------+-----+
|eventid|count|
+-------+-----+
|3328   |2    |
+-------+-----+
```

So questions:

1. For the first file, why there are 2 batches and one batch is empty?
2. Why the late-arrival data out of watermark not get rejected and still get aggregated?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd observe logs to see the watermark (it should be at INFO). I suspect that the time is in incorrect format. What Spark is that?

Comment: Thanks Jacek. It is Spark 2.4.3. I'm using IntelliJ. 
When there is a single row in file:
2019-08-02 10:10:00,1,3328,c1,10,1000
There are 2 batches for this file with single row:
`
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-------+-----+
|eventid|count|
+-------+-----+
|3328   |1    |
+-------+-----+
`

Comment: The log is:
```
"batchId" : 0,
"numInputRows" : 1,
...
"eventTime" : {
    "avg" : "2019-08-04T17:10:00.000Z",
    "max" : "2019-08-04T17:10:00.000Z",
    "min" : "2019-08-04T17:10:00.000Z",
    "watermark" : "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+-------+-----+
|eventid|count|
+-------+-----+
+-------+-----+
...
"eventTime" : {
    "watermark" : "2019-08-04T17:09:55.000Z"
  },
```

Comment: From above what happened is the first time no watermark. After reading the first row, it set the water mark correctly to max event time - 5sec = "2019-08-04T17:09:55.000Z". Then I add another file with only one single row but change the time to 2 days ago: 2019-08-02 10:10:00,1,3328,c1,10,1000

Comment: `-------------------------------------------
Batch: 2
-------------------------------------------
+-------+-----+
|eventid|count|
+-------+-----+
|3328   |2    |
+-------+-----+
 "eventTime" : {
    "avg" : "2019-08-02T17:10:00.000Z",
    "max" : "2019-08-02T17:10:00.000Z",
    "min" : "2019-08-02T17:10:00.000Z",
    "watermark" : "2019-08-04T17:09:55.000Z"
  }`

Comment: The eventTime is 2019-08-02T17:10:00.000Z, which is earlier than watermark, but still counted.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add all the info (properly formatted)? Thanks!

Comment: Basically from log I can clearly see when event time is 2019-08-02T17:10:00.000Z and "watermark" : "2019-08-04T17:09:55.000Z". 
event time is 2 days earlier than watermark. 
From [document](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#semantic-guarantees-of-aggregation-with-watermarking)
However, the guarantee is strict only in one direction. Data delayed by more than 2 hours is not guaranteed to be dropped; it may or may not get aggregated. More delayed is the data, less likely is the engine going to process it.

Comment: This might be ok for rank agg like 'get earliest row', but too bad for agg like count. This means the count behavior is not predictable.
I tried 2.4.4, still the same.

Comment: For batch 2 the log is `"eventTime" : { 
    "avg" : "2019-08-02T17:10:00.000Z", 
    "max" : "2019-08-02T17:10:00.000Z", 
    "min" : "2019-08-02T17:10:00.000Z", 
    "watermark" : "2019-08-04T17:09:55.000Z" }`

Answer (score 0):

may be:`to_timestamp($"eventid")`  would solve the problem.